# Weblogic - ClassNotFoundException - during deployment

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, weblogic12c

during deployment on weblogic server (after upgrade it to the newest version) I received exception like below. My project is build from few war and jar files into the one ear. I checked whether this class is placed in specific war file and that this war is part of the ear file.

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: (here is a path to the class in my project)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: (here is a path to the class in my project)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:72)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doParentDelegate(GenericClassLoader.java:584)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:526)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:473)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.BeanInfoImpl.loadClass(BeanInfoImpl.java:413)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.BeanInfoImpl.loadForSure(BeanInfoImpl.java:418)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.SessionBeanInfoImpl.prepare(SessionBeanInfoImpl.java:467)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.setupBeanInfos(EJBDeployer.java:580)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:733)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EjbModuleExtension.postPrepare(EjbModuleExtension.java:101)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:297)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Do you know where should I search for the resolution of this problem? I checked a lot of similar themes on web but without any success in my situation. if you need any additional information just ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check if that jar is included in MANIFEST.MF of your war

Comment: In my case the JAR is in the .war manifest, and other classes from the same JAR are loaded (verified by using -verbose:class in WL). Only a single class is not loaded.